# Make Unique Objects by Passing Parameters to our Constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor

**Make Unique Objects by Passing Parameters to our Constructor**:

The constructor we have is great, but what if we don't always want to create the same object?

To solve this we can add parameters to our constructor. We do this like the following example:

```
var Car = function(wheels, seats, engines) {
  this.wheels = wheels;
  this.seats = seats;
  this.engines = engines;
};
```

Now we can pass in arguments when we call our constructor.

```
var myCar = new Car(6, 3, 1);
```

This code will create an object that uses the arguments we passed in and looks like:

```
{
  wheels: 6,
  seats: 3,
  engines: 1
}
```

Now give it a try yourself! Alter the `Car constructor` to use `parameters` to assign values to the `wheels, seats, and engines` properties.

Then call your new `constructor` with three number arguments and assign it to `myCar` to see it in action.

---

> Please complete the code given below :

```
  var Car = function() {
  //Change this constructor
  this.wheels = 4;
  this.seats = 1;
  this.engines = 1;
};

//Try it out here
var myCar;
```

> Instructions :

- Calling `new Car(3,1,2)` should produce an object with a `wheels`
  property of 3, a `seats` property of 1, and an `engines` property of 2.
- Calling `new Car(4,4,2)` should produce an object with a `wheels`
  property of 4, a `seats` property of 4, and an `engines` property of 2.
- Calling `new Car(2,6,3)` should produce an object with a `wheels`
  property of 2, a `seats` property of 6, and an `engines` property of 3.
- `myCar` should have number values for the `wheels, seats, and engines`
  properties.

---

> My attempt :

```
var Car = function() {
  //Change this constructor
  this.wheels = 4;
  this.seats = 1;
  this.engines = 1;
};

//Try it out here
var myCar = function(wheels, seats, engines) {
  this.wheels = wheels;
  this.seats = seats;
  this.engines = engines;
};
 var myCar = new Car(6, 3, 1);
```

Comment: I want fill code according given instructions. link http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/make-unique-objects-by-passing-parameters-to-our-constructor#?solution=var%20Car%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2FChange%20this%20constructor%0A%20%20this.wheels%20%3D%204%3B%0A%20%20this.seats%20%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20this.engines%20%3D%201%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2FTry%20it%20out%20here%0Avar%20myCar%3B%0A

Comment: Your instructions fulfil your first code snippet. So please, show us what Instruction fails, when you using the first  `Car` constructor.

Comment: Do yo want `new Car(3,1,2)` always return the reference to the **same** object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding challenge answer for the link you added will be :

```
var Car = function(wheels, seats, engines) {
 if(isNaN(wheels))
    wheels = 0;
 if(isNaN(seats))
    seats = 0;
 if(isNaN(engines))
    engines = 0;
  this.wheels = wheels;
  this.seats = seats;
  this.engines = engines;
};
//Try it out here
var myCar = new Car(2,6,3);
myCar = new Car(3,1,2);
myCar = new Car(4,4,2);
```

Run tests after adding this code. - all will pass

Answer (score 1):

You answered already yourself:

```
var Car = function(wheels, seats, engines) {
  //additional checks
  if(isNaN(wheels))
      wheels = 0;
  if(isNaN(seats))
      seats = 0;
  if(isNaN(engines))
      engines = 0;
  this.wheels = wheels;
  this.seats = seats;
  this.engines = engines;
};

//Try it out here
var myCar = new Car(3,1,2);
console.dir(myCar);

myCar = new Car(4,4,2);
console.dir(myCar);

myCar = new Car(2,6,3);
console.dir(myCar);
```